# Converting all text in specific element to uppercase?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to convert all table header text to uppercase but not successful.

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>product name</th>
<th>product id</th>
....
```

My script is as follow:

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementByTagName('th').innerHTML;
document.write(x.toUpperCase());
</script>
```

Please help....I am learning JS and almost frustrated by this simple thing.

Answer (score 7):

I would consider using CSS for this instead of javascript.

```
th {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: This would be a good way to go, however proper use of `getElementsByTagName` is still a good technique to learn so you have it for other needed cases.

Answer (score 4):

If this is just for presentation, you'd probably be better of just using CSS:

```
th {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

But if you really need to do it in JS:

```
var headers = document.getElementsByTagName("th");
for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
  var header = headers[i];
  header.innerHTML = header.innerHTML.toUpperCase();
}
```

The problem with your code is that the method `getElementByTagName` does not exist. You have to fetch all of the s, cycle through them and apply it to each one.

Answer (score 1):

### ***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/bqxBW/)***

As Brandon points out, you should really do this with css. However, if you wanted a js example of how to do it:

```
var headers = document.getElementsByTagName('th');
for( var i = 0, len = headers.length; i < len; i++ ){
 headers[i].innerHTML = headers[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: The reason why this is the right way to do it is that the word "Element" in the method name is actually plural, meaning that it returns an array of Element objects.

The only javascript method like that which will always return at most one object is `getElementById` since there can (read: should) only be one object with the given ID on the page. If there are more with the same ID, you won't be able to find them as it will quit looking after the first.